# How to put ListView inside the horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android

I want to put `ListView` inside the horizontal `ScrollView` in Android.
Our requirement is that I want scroll screen horizontally.
So can I put `ListView` inside the `ScrollView`?

Comment: Show us what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `ListView` inside a `ViewFlipper`,
e.g.: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example

You can even consider `ViewPager`.

Comment: Please send a sample that show how come use viewflipper for Listeview with horizontal feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `ListView` in a horizontal `ScrollView` or add some details.